# savetrees and \verbatim interact badly

Tags: verbatim, savetrees

My MWE

```
$ cat test1.tex
\documentclass{article}
%usepackage{savetrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range (3):
            plot(i,j,k) # aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            plot(j,k,i) #               b
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
$ diff test1.tex test2.tex 
2c2
< %usepackage{savetrees}
---
> \usepackage{savetrees}
$
```

Running `pdflatex test1` produces

[image]

while `pdflatex test2` produces

[image]

It looks like spaces are not the same width as fixed width characters...

Is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: hmm. I can't reproduce this. The margins are smaller with `savetrees`. But the verbatim text looks the same.

Comment: Make sure your distribution is all up to date.

Comment: Ohhhh! Are you compiling with `xelatex` by any chance? I do see the difference with `xelatex`. (`pdflatex` and `lualatex` are fine.)

Comment: I have compiled with `pdflatex`, with `lualatex` and with `xelatex` as well and because I've got same misfit with all the engines I've decided to post only the `pdflatex` runs.  Re the up-to-date-ness, I run Debian unstable and the package version is `2018.20190227-2`

Comment: hmmm. I don't know then if you get problems with all engines. I run Debian testing and I'm at version `2018.20190131-1`. An immediate workaround might be to use `\usepackage[wordspacing=normal]{savetrees}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No tabs.  Re `\showoutput`, isn't it a bit longish to post here?

Comment: @DavidPurton `\usepackage[wordspacing=normal]{savetrees}` is what I need.  If you like to write an answer I'll upvote and possibly accept it.

Comment: @gboffi, it works. But it also has other side effects. The word spacing will loosen a bit in normal text too. Someone may be able to find the real issue and provide a proper fix. I don't think word spacing should change for fixed pitch fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I do get spacing differences. But I can't figure it out. The difference is not pronounced with `pdflatex`. The `b` seems to protrude a bit actually. But with `xelatex` and `lualatex` I get similar output as screenshots above. With `pdflatex` and without `savetrees`, the characters are `\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 a` and the spaces are `\glue 5.24995`. With `savetrees` I see lots of `\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10/-25ls a` and `\glue 5.1187`. With `xelatex` without `savetrees` I see `\TU/lmtt/m/n/10 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` and `\glue 5.25`. With `savetrees` I see same for the `a`s and `\glue 4.20001`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, with `lualatex` without `savetrees` I see `\TU/lmtt/m/n/10 a` and `\glue(\spaceskip) 5.25`. With `savetrees` I see `\TU/lmtt/m/n/10 a` and `\glue(\spaceskip) 4.20001`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I notice my `microtype` version is a bit old. `2018/01/14 v2.7`. That could account for some issues. But it doesn't get loaded for `xelatex`. Same version of `savetrees`.

Comment: Upgrading `microtype` makes no difference for me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Without `savetrees`: `....\glue 5.24995
....\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 a`  —  with it `....\glue 5.1187
....\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10/-25ls a`.  All of the above with `pdflatex`.

Comment: OK yes I see a difference in the log now, although the visual difference in pdf was not as you showed, I cleaned up some of my older comments I may try to trace later